# Как запустить vimeo корректно?

Tags: javascript

Чтобы по кастомной кнопке он запускался ( и скрывалась кнопка)

```js
$(document).on('click', '.result__play', function(e) {
  $(".result__video iframe")[0].src += "&autoplay=1";
  $('.result__play').hide();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.result__video {
  max-height: 95vh;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
}

.result__video iframe {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  border: none;
}

.result__play {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 122;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: block;
  width: 118px;
  height: 118px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="result__video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/10985679?h=7008dd1c79" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
  <button class="result__play">btn</button>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" integrity="sha256-JlqSTELeR4TLqP0OG9dxM7yDPqX1ox/HfgiSLBj8+kM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: А что сейчас не работает?

Comment: https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#vimeo